# Asking for location permission only appears when app is interrupted

Tags: android, google-maps, permissions, location

I am developing an android application that uses Google Maps.
The expected behavior is:

1. Enter the map activity
2. Ask user to use his location
3. Show nearby places

When I run the application using an emulator in Android Studio , the flow is the expected one (Pixel 2 Api 30), but when I run it on my phone, the permission is only asked for after I stop the application run.

Why is  this happening?

### Acitivity

```
public class NearbyPharmaciesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double latitude, longitude;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private Marker marker;
    private GoogleMapsApi mService;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_pharmacies);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        // Init service
        mService = RetrofitGoogleMaps.getApi();

        // Request runtime permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_pharmacy:
                        nearbyPlaces("pharmacy");
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        buildLocationCallBack();
        buildLocationRequest();
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }

    private boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                }, MY_PERMISSION_CODE);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                }, MY_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        buildLocationCallBack();
                        buildLocationRequest();
                        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
                        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private void buildLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(300000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(30);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    private void buildLocationCallBack() {
        System.out.println("Reached here");
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                lastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                System.out.println("last location: " + lastLocation.toString());
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }

                latitude = lastLocation.getLatitude();
                longitude = lastLocation.getLongitude();
                System.out.println("LATITUDE: " + latitude);
                System.out.println("LONGITUDE: " + longitude);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title("Your position")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
                //LocationData locationData = new LocationData(latitude, longitude);*/

                //mDatabase.child("location").child(userId).child(String.valueOf(new Date().getTime())).setValue(locationData);

                //getMarkers();

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {

                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void nearbyPlaces(final String placeType) {
        String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, placeType);
        System.out.println("URL: "+ url);

        mService.getNearByPlaces(url)
                .enqueue(new Callback<SearchResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<SearchResponse> call, Response<SearchResponse> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            System.out.println("Sucesso");

                            for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getResults().length; i++) {
                                System.out.println("ENTRA NO IF");
                                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                                Result googlePlace = response.body().getResults()[i];
                                double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.getGeometry().getLocation().getLat());
                                double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.getGeometry().getLocation().getLng());
                                String placeName = googlePlace.getName();
                                String vicinity = googlePlace.getVicinity();
                                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                                markerOptions.title(placeName);
                                if (placeType.equals("pharmacy")) {
                                    System.out.println("BEM");
                                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("CONA");
                                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                                }

                                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<SearchResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String placeType) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        builder.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
        builder.append("&radius=10000");
        builder.append("&type=" + placeType);
        builder.append("&sensor=true");
        builder.append("&key=" + "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        Log.d("getUrl", builder.toString());
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot ask for [foreground and background](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#request-background-location) location permission at the same time, you have to do it incrementally.

Comment: @Pawel by incrementally you mean ask for one and only then for the other?

Comment: @FábioPires , yes , ask background location only when user has approved foreground location, You can look at google sample code how it's implemented - [LocationUpdatesBackgroundKotlin](https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/main/LocationUpdatesBackgroundKotlin)

Comment: @Nitish but why does this work fine in the android studio emulator and doesn't work fine in my phone?

Comment: @Nitish is foreground FINE_LOCATION?

Comment: Yes `FINE_LOCATION` and `COARSE_LOCATION`  are for foreground. Do you have same OS in both emulator and phone? Only for Android 11 and above , you have to ask location incrementally , for lower android version it works fine. Also as of latest updated in Android 12 , when access [` FINE_LOCATION` , `COARSE_LOCATION` is mandatory to ask](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#approximate-request)

Comment: @Nitish my phone is Android 10 but it's on my phone that the error occurs. What I find strange is that if I interrupt the run it asks for the permission

Comment: Sorry I'm out of options here. Could you debug your app , maybe some exception/error is being thrown which we are unable to see. Maybe `onMapReady` get's called before the permission is requested, debug will show the flow and what's really happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

This happened because I asked for permissions in two separate occasions.
First I would ask for SMS permissions in my Main Activity and then, when entering this Activity I would ask for location permissions.

In android development you must ask for all permissions at once.